# PYTHON 3.7 _tkinter.TclError: invalid command name "tixBalloon"

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, tix

Hello I am trying to create a button that will show description when hovered. similar to html img tag "alt" 
I decide to use "tkinter.pix" with Balloon()
But I am having an error:
 _tkinter.TclError: invalid command name "tixBalloon".

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import tix


class MyClass:

    def __init__(self, master):
        self.master = master
        self.btn_1 = Button(self.master, text="Button")
        self.btn_1.pack()

        self.bal = tix.Balloon(self.master)

        self.bal.bind_widget(self.btn_1, balloonmsg="Hello")
root = Tk()
app= MyClass(root)
root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

When you use `tix` widgets, you also need to use the `tix` version of `Tk()`.
So replace `root = Tk()` with:

```
root = tix.Tk()
```

Comment: And so how will we be using it? Please provide the usage and what will be the full code look like?

Comment: I'm afraid I don't understand what you're getting at. There's code in the question that produces an error, I explain the normal `Tk()` should be replaced by the `tix` one and show how that line should look. Replacing that one line in the code from the question makes it work. What more code should I provide?

Comment: hello, is it possible to change the background color? I tried self.bal.config(bg="red") but only the border turned red.

Comment: @Van It is possible, but it's too much to explain in a comment and it's a completely different question. You could ask a new question if you can't find an answer yourself.